# wordpress - show comments only comments who are approved

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

i am building some kind of a comments archive, 
i was looking here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

and saw no "array" that can help me...

this is part of my code:

```
    function process_post(){ 
    Function sheker()  { 
    $args = array(
      what to put here ??????????????
    );

    // The Query
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );



  // Comment Loop
```

any ideas ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress usage, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: don't put anything... it'll return each comment

Comment: it is returning all the comments ever added, even the ones who are not approved (spam etc.). i need to filter somehow so that only the ones who are approved will be shawn in the archive. added the full code

Comment: @ShivanRaptor This is not off-topic at all. Questions about Wordpress are common here, but will generally get an answer more quickly on the dedicated Stack Exchange.

Comment: @maiorano84 Disagree. It's about WordPress API usage. Redundant to WPSE scope. If this is not off-topic, the WPSE has no use. SO is for general programming question, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using following code you can get all comments that are approved ([Check Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query#Properties))

```
$args = array('status'=>'approve');
$comments = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );
```